# MySQL - Same Data Problems

Tags: mysql

I apologise for the rushed posting.

The following are images of what I have:

Table 1 called 'players'
[image: Table players]

Table 2 called 'Reports'
[image]

And this is the format that I want the table to be displayed in:

[image]

I have tried using simple 'join' and 'and' statments and using some other's that I found on here. Still no avail.

Any help would be great.

Comment: show tables sql, create and insert statements. then show what the result should look like

Comment: Updated with information, I'm not inserting any of the elements through mysql. Simply displaying them. Logging is taken care of from the game server end.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to get the data and display it on the administrative section of the site for my moderation team. The data is all there and correct, I just can't get it to display correctly. The feature is a report system for users to report rule breakers etc. THe first name the name of the user being reported, and the reporter is the name of the person executing the command. They both use a UUID, due to name changes. I have 1 table with the name and UUID's, but i can't query the table to get the two different UUID's I need and convert them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure i understand, but i think that's is what you need:

```
  SELECT `t2`.`id`,`t1`.`name` `Reported Name`, `t12`.`name` `Reporting Name`
  FROM `test`.`Reports` `t2`
  JOIN `test`.`players` `t1` 
    on `t1`.`id`=`t2`.`reported_uid`
  join `test`.`players` `t12` 
    on `t12`.`id`=`t2`.`reporting_uid`;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/360d2/1/0

Comment: This is somewhat close. I am getting the error saying that players is not a unique table. The table names are 'players' and 'Reports'. Any chance you can modify your query with the tables names in the right spot?

Comment: Can you check it now? Try this on fiddle link.

Comment: Still haven't managed to get it to work :( I can provide a picture of the table headers if that helps in anyway?

Comment: I cant remember, claimant is a foreign key which points to user UUID right? Do you need to cross this two tables ON claimant = players.UUID??

Comment: Sorry, forgot to close this. Your answer help and got me to the spot that I needed. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Ohah that it's a little unclear, but I'll take a shot at it.  If you're just trying to show all of Table 2 with one of the name fields from Table 1, you could do it this way:

```
SELECT t1.Example_Name, t2.*
FROM
Table_2 t2
JOIN Table_1 t1 ON t1.Name_1 = t2.User_Reported
```

- Table 1 = t1 (t1 is an alias to Table 1 so you don't have to type the whole name out)
- Table 2 = t2 (t2 is an alias to Table 2)
- "Example_Name" is whichever field you want from the first table

The main question is how the two tables are related and what data you want to get from each.  But I hope this helps.